# Homotopy class of maps to a complex projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $M$ be a closed oriented smooth 4-manifold. Denote by $[M, \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}]$ homotopy classes of continuous maps from $M$ to $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$.

I would like to know how to show
$$ [M, \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}]=[M,\mathbb{C}P^2].$$

I know that $\mathbb{C}P^2$ has (real) dimension 4 so the above equation looks plausible. But I would like to know a rigorous proof.

I am not familiar the complex projective space except its definition nor homotopy theory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $\Bbb{CP}^2$ is a subcomplex of $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$, the latter having a CW structure with a single cell in every even dimension. Because smooth manifolds are triangulable, they have a CW structure, so [cellular approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem) says that (because $M$ has dimension at most $4$ - so all the cells in the triangulation are dimension at most $4$) every map $f: M \to \Bbb{CP}^\infty$ is homotopic to a map $g_1: M \to \Bbb{CP}^2$. If $f$ is also homotopic to $g_2: M \to \Bbb{CP}^2$, then $g_1$ and $g_2$ are also homotopic (again invoke cellular approximation - there are no cells in odd dimensions in our cell structure on $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$). So we have a canonical map $[M,\Bbb{CP}^\infty] \to [M,\Bbb{CP}^2]$; surjectivity is obvious and if two maps $f_i: M \to \Bbb{CP}^\infty$ are homotopic to the same map $M \to \Bbb{CP}^2$, they're homotopic, so the map is a bijection as desired.

Comment: I don't actually need smoothness; Kirby-Siebenmann's book "Foundational essays on Topological Manifolds" has a proof that every compact topological manifold is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex and I suspect - but don't know, and don't have the book to check - that this CW complex has dimension at most the dimension of the manifold.

Comment: Edit: I don't *think I actually need smoothness.

Comment: Yes, in all dimensions but 4 they prove existence of a handle decomposition, which is all you need. In dimension 4, existence of a CW  decomposition is open, but the result you need might follow from Freedman and Quinn.